# Adding custom pins to bing map in Windows Store app

Tags: windows, windows-8, bing-maps, bing, windows-store-apps

I'm new to C# and am working on a Windows Store App that lets a user tap locations on a map to place a marker, save a title and a description for that location. I found the overlayItem class for Android is similar to what I need for my app as it includes a Geopoint and 2 Strings for each overlayItem. 
I have searched for C# examples to use in my app already but end up going in circles, so I was just wondering if there is a class out there already that may be suitable, or whether it would be better to make my own?
I was thinking something along the lines of this and to make my own get and set methods:

```
class windowsOverlayItem{
Location loc;
String title;
String description;
Pushpin pin;
}
```

I've found a few map examples but none that really go to any depth. 
Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out, that tag and name can be used for the info I need to save for each pushpin along with the location.
Here's a short example of when I want to add a new Pushpin to my map and save some details to it.

```
MyMap.Children.Add(newpin);
MapLayer.SetPosition(newpin, loc);
newpin.Name = title;
newpin.Tag = newpin.Tag as String;
newpin.Tag = description;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Bing Maps C# Pushpin Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bing-Maps-Pushpin-Sample-a10f582b) implements exactly that. Take a look at its code for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike. That pushpin sample was the one I was going by mostly. So far my app places a pushpin in my current location and when I tap it, a dialog box shows "you are here". I can also click anywhere on the map and more markers will be placed in these locations. What I'm really stuck on is the best way to click a location, have some sort of text input box for the user to enter details about that location and place a pushpin, so that when the pushpin clicked again it will display the details entered previously. I can post the main part of my code if that would help?